# Problems with designing website with tables and css

Tags: html, css

I know how to code, but designing aligning positioning is a burden.

I tried working with css, with tables, html and asp.net but cannot get the site to a professional level of design.

problems like

- the spacing between rows is too much, sometimes too less
- sometimes the row increases in height because of one single problematic dynamic control destroying the complete visual effect!

How should I get better on web page designing?

Comment: did you consider a training or a study? Normally when I got stuck with structural stuff like this, I dive in to it and try to master it. http://www.quirksmode.org/ and http://www.alistapart.com/topics/ are good ways to start reading. wax-in, wax-out ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pick up a copy of any good CSS book like the ones listed below. In addition, you will find plenty of stuff on the web, try and experiment as much as possible without giving up easily. Read about the Box Model, Inline/Block/Floated elements, Margins/Padding, Relative/Absolute/Fixed positioning

[CSS Mastery](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1590596145)

[Cascading Style Sheets O'Reilly](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1565926226)

Answer (score 1):

well the only way to learn is learn css and make good uses if it...see how the other webpages are developed and try to implement it in your project..

Answer (score 1):

I suggest getting yourself an HTML/CSS debugging tool like Firebug, which is a plugin for Firefox. You can browse to an element and see what CSS it has on it, and modify it on the fly. That will help you see what different things margins, padding, height, and width do.

You should probably try to understand the box model more than anything. That governs how items are laid out on-screen.

http://css-tricks.com/the-css-box-model/

Stick with the pure CSS solution whenever possible. You'll find that maintenance becomes easier in the long run.

Answer (score 1):

tables is not a true way for designing.. and for design table reset this attribute in tables :

```
colls="0" rows="0"
```